# Positioning Elements without Absolute Positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I have 3 columns, using Bootstrap 3 grid system. Each column has varying amounts of text and with a button below it. I want to align the 3 buttons vertically, but I cannot use `position:absolute` and `bottom:x` because it breaks the responsive nature of the grid.

You can see the example here: http://codepen.io/enjay43/pen/tvcCD

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a height for each column's top block.
See this fork I've made [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AwKnm)